# Compilation fails using Chapel on a mac

Tags: macos, chapel

Using a stock install of Chapel (via Homebrew) on a Mac running Big Sur. Tried to compile one of the example programs:

`chpl /usr/local/Cellar/chapel/1.27.0/libexec/examples/hello.chpl`

followed with

```
mv: rename /var/folders/81/9s9zv6450td9kgh_znllq52000037c/T//chpl-username.deleteme-nJkMMc/hello.tmp to hello: No such file or directory
error: mv /var/folders/81/9s9zv6450td9kgh_znllq52000037c/T//chpl-username.deleteme-nJkMMc/hello.tmp hello
error: Make Binary - Linking
```

Looks like a simple fix, but would appreciate suggestions. (And annoyingly, am trying to (eventually!) do a local compile of a package I contributed to)

R.

Comment: We recently found a previously unknown weakness in our code base that caused problems with the homebrew formula when paths of compilers changed (which has apparently happened since the Chapel 1.27.0 release) whose failure mode matches yours.  The following homebrew PR was merged around the same time as you filed your issue and _should_ resolve this failure mode https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/107405.  Meanwhile https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/20385 is the longer-term fix to our code base (not yet merged).

Comment: Thanks -- the latest homebrew version does indeed fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted and verified in the comments above, this seems to have been a recently discovered issue in our code base that can be worked around in homebrew for the time being by doing a `brew update`.  It ought to be fixed in a more principled manner in Chapel 1.28.0 and onwards.  If others see this failure mode going forward, please consider opening [a GitHub issue on the Chapel repository](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) so that we can help you work through it.